# I am trying to understand predict()

Tags: r, predict

I am trying to understand the predict() operation in R. If I run this set of R code:

```
growth <- c(12,10,8,11,6,7,2,3,3)
tannin <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
plot(growth, tannin, pch = 20, col = "blue")
model <- lm(growth ~ tannin)
new.d <- data.frame(tannin = seq(0,10, 0.5))
mod2 <- predict(model, newdata = new.d, se.fit = T, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
col <- c("red", "green", "green")
plot(tannin, growth, pch = 20, col = "blue")
matlines(new.d$tannin, mod2$fit[,1:3], col = col, lty =2)
```

I get a scatterplot of the data and some nice confidence intervals lines

but if I run this set of R code:

```
y.hat <- c(973.6536, 1620.5231, 882.3643, 1529.2338, 1266.6586, 1281.8735, 1205.7990, 928.0090, 1574.8784, 1297.0883, 1190.5841, 1251.4437, 1187.5412, 1305.3495)
gain <- c(1004, 1636, 852, 1506, 1272, 1270, 1269, 903, 1555, 1260, 1146, 1276, 1225, 1321)
plot(y.hat, gain, pch = 20, col = "blue")
model.2 <- lm(gain ~ y.hat)
new.d.2 <- data.frame(gain = seq(800,1700, length.out = 14))
mod.3 <- predict(model.2, newdata = new.d.2, se.fit = T, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)
matlines(new.d.2$gain, mod.3$fit[,1:3], col = col, lty = 2)
```

The scatterplot is normal but the confidence lines are all weird.

Please help me understand why.

Thanks Kirk

Comment: In the second you are running a model that predicts `gain` given `y.hat` (`gain~y.hat`). So when you predict, you should be passing in values of `y.hat` but you are not. Since there are no values in of `y.hat` in your data.frame it finds the values in the global environment and just returns the fitted values in the order they appear in the data. So i'm not sure if your model is wrong or if your new data is wrong, but currently these don't match up.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is interesting that such a silly mistake can be so frustrating, yet I will not forget now.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrFlick pointed out, your predict function is probabily wrong...

If you want to predict the values based on "GAIN", since gain is your input at the predict() function, then your lm function should be `lm(y.hat ~ gain)` and your graph will look good.

```r
col <- c("red", "green", "green")
y.hat <- c(973.6536, 1620.5231, 882.3643, 1529.2338, 1266.6586, 1281.8735, 1205.7990, 928.0090, 1574.8784, 1297.0883, 1190.5841, 1251.4437, 1187.5412, 1305.3495)
gain <- c(1004, 1636, 852, 1506, 1272, 1270, 1269, 903, 1555, 1260, 1146, 1276, 1225, 1321)

model.2 <- lm(y.hat ~ gain)

new.d.2 <- data.frame(gain = seq(800,1700, length.out = 14))
mod.3 <- predict(model.2, newdata = new.d.2, se.fit = T, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)

plot(gain, y.hat, pch = 20, col = "blue")
matlines(new.d.2$gain, mod.3$fit[,1:3], col = col, lty = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>